# How to replace string values with numeric inside a json object used in google visualization api column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization, str-replace

I have this Json string that i use for google chart visualization that needs to be in this exact format and i need to replace every value of "v" that is a number to its numeric value( the value without the ""). I should do some javascript replace function, but i couldn't find a way to move around the json object. Here is and example json string that i should modify :

```
{"cols":[
{"id":"r","label":"Reason","type":"string"},
{"id":"m","label":"Minutes","type":"number"}
],
"rows":[
{"c":[
     {"v":"Flour - Blower","f":"Flour - Blower"},
     {"v":"7","f":"7"}]},
{"c":[
     {"v":"Whole Line - d","f":"Whole Line - d"},
     {"v":"4","f":"4"}]},
{"c":[
     {"v":"Flour - Pipework","f":"Flour - Pipework"},
     {"v":"3","f":"3"}]},
{"c":[
     {"v":"Horseshoe - Belt","f":"Horseshoe - Belt"},
     {"v":"1","f":"1"}]}
],
"p":null
}
```

probably i should do something like :

```
var jsonStr = ...;

for (i in jsonStr.rows) {
   for(j in jsonStr[i].c)
   { 
    if (parseInt(jsonStr[i].c[j].v) != 'NaN') {
        jsonStr.rows[i].c[j].v = parseInt(jsonStr.rows[i].c[j].v);
   }
 }
```

Comment: instead of parsing the whole array why don't you do the isNaN() and parseInt where you actually want to use these values ?

Comment: `parseInt` for a non-parseable argument returns `NaN`, not `'NaN'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since JSON is effectively a string, why not put the entire string through a global `string.replace`:

```
jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonStr);
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/"v":"(\d+)"/g, '"v":$1');
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjxSD/)

Comment: +1, but should be followed by `jsonStr = JSON.parse(jsonStr);`

Comment: I omitted that, as the op says he has a JSON string, not an object. I stringified it for demo purposes.

Comment: you need to do the same thing with the 'f' part as well `.replace(/"f":"(\d+)"/g, '"f":$1');` http://jsfiddle.net/LjxSD/1/

Comment: @QambarRaza if needed, can do `jsonStr.replace(/"(v|f)":"(\d+)"/g, '"$1":$2');`

Comment: thanks, this is working fine. I actually do not have to parse the f part it should be string everywhere where f stands for format of the value to be shown in the characteristics. I've tested it on my charts and it is working okay ;]

Answer (score 2):

Well, the parsing seems okay to me. It's probably not working because you can't really check if a string contains a number or not by comparing something with `NaN`

This is because even `NaN === NaN`, famously, returns `false`.

I'd suggest that you use the isNaN method (which does use parseInt internally). So, something like this ought to work

```
for (i in jsonStr.rows) {
   for(j in jsonStr[i].c)
   { 
    if (!isNaN(jsonStr[i].c[j].v)) {
        jsonStr.rows[i].c[j].v = parseInt(jsonStr.rows[i].c[j].v);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns string if isNaN else a number:

```
function convertNumberToInteger(val) {
    if (isNaN(val)) {
        return val;
    } else {
        return parseInt(val);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
convertNumberToInteger("sasdfasdf");
Output: "sasdfasdf"

convertNumberToInteger("3");
Output: 3
```

And if you really want to parse it you can do a forEach on the JSON object

Comment: The function body can be a one-liner: `return isNaN(val) ? val : +val;`. But OP's stated problem is how to navigate the JSON structure, not how to convert a single value.

Comment: @TedHopp is right ;] I know how to replace or extract value. The thing was that i couldn't navigate through the json properties to replace only the values i needed.